# Hosting minecraft server via webmin on Ubuntu

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am trying to host Ubuntu on webmin and everything is going perfectly, but I can only join my server when I run minecraft 1.5.2 which I obviously dont want to. I think I have the wrong Minecraft Server Module for webmin. How do I get the right one and cant I just make it update automatically or something?

Comment: Looks to me like you should be asking webmin for that module. Why not just download the minecraft server jar from mojang and run `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar`?

Comment: @Cole That wouldn't be managed by webmin then, would it?

Comment: @Loko I *believe* that the module doesn't actually care too much about the version (apart from its updates feature), meaning you can just download the newest `minecraft_server.jar`, put it in the webmin Minecraft directory (which is controlled by the module's `config` file) and it'll just work.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'll try it out when I am home but how do I run that command in linux? I am still a beginner.

Comment: @Loko Webmin is already running the command for you. You *should* just have to give it a different copy of the server .jar where it normally expects the existing copy to be.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Again a bit of a noob here but do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Loko First locate your webmin modules and configuration directories. Other sites and google should help figure that out. Then read the Minecraft server module's config file, which will tell you where the .jar lives.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ok so I found a line with a textfield next to it called:"Full path to minecraft jar file" so I filled in a directory and I got this error when trying to start the server:"lost connection Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/loko/Downloads/minecraft_server.1.7.2.jar "

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Invalid or corrupt jarfile /home/loko/Downloads/

Comment: @Loko encapsulate that in quotes. I don't use webmin I use cronjobs. Ubuntu has them if you are completely new to linux then you would run `sudo crontab -e` and append `@reboot /usr/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar /home/loko/.minecraft/server/minecraft_server.jar` This would be based on you saving the new server in your .minecraft directory in a folder called server and the server jar being called "minecraft_server.jar" I would also add that -Xmx1024M only allocates <1024MB of RAM. To have more ram increase that value to something like -Xmx4096M for 4GB RAM. BUT thats my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your webmin run Minecraft_Server.1.7.2.jar:

1. Download the jar to your desktop
2. Open a Terminal
3. Run: `sudo mv /home/yourusernamehere/Desktop/minecraft_server.1.7.2.jar /usr/local/minecraft/minecraft_server.jar`
4. Test with the ['Minecraft Server 1.5'](http://www.webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?recent=1) module for webmin
5. Execute

**EXPLANATION OF TASK # 3**:

> SUDO -- execute with higher privileges
>
> MV -- move file #1 from /location/A/file#1 to /location/B/file#1nameORfile#1renamed

Judging by the source code in the module provided, this **SHOULD** work. I'm not a webmin user, but I do know enough linux to understand what is going on under the hood aka 'to be dangerous'.

PLEASE NOTE: The module only provides 1GB of RAM to minecraft by default, if you find yourself needing more open the wbm and locate the line similar to:

`java_args=-Xms1G -Xmx1G -D`

and change it to

`java_args=-Xms4G -Xmx4G -D`

for 4GB of RAM allocation to minecraft or to have a range:

`java_args=-Xms1G -Xmx4G -D` which will give you a minimum of 1GB but no more than 4GB.

### TO MANUALLY INSTALL the module:

1. Download from here: http://download.webmin.com/download/modules/minecraft-1.5.wbm.gz
2. Unpack on Desktop and make modifications above
3. Repack the archive (`cd ~/Desktop; rm ~/Desktop/minecraft-1.5.wbm.gz; gzip minecraft-1.5.wbm; mv minecraft-1.5.wbm.gz minecraft.wbm.gz`)
4. Goto webmin
5. Click "Webmin Configuration"
6. Click "Webmin Modules"
7. Click the Radio button for "From Local File"
8. Click the ellipsis at the end of the "From Local File" line and select the modified minecraft.wbm.gz
9. Click "Install Module"

Steps written from memory, so compression may be different as everyone doesn't use the same Desktop Manager/Window Manager. Please comment if you have an issue with a particular step.

### Automatically updating minecraft server for webmin:

*SOON TO BE BUILT USING WGET AND A BASH SCRIPT*

### Will updating affect my minecraft world?

**ONLY** as much as the update affects the game. Built structures *should* be okay.

### How do I host it publically?

[**NOIP.com**](http://www.noip.com) free DNS. Don't worry about IP addresses.

[Port Forward](http://portforward.com/) is a thing.

In Ubuntu Linux Distributions: `ufw` may cause you grief.

### Should I worry about something else?

[Security Questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

[Ubuntu Based Questions](http://askubuntu.com)

[Programming/Scripting Questions](http://stackoverflow.com)

[Other linux distribution questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

### [Where do I get Minecraft Server?](http://www.minecraft.net/download)

### Are You affliated with any company listed?

No I am not, But they are very reliable resources, until NOIP shuts down free managed DNS hosting.

Comment: Kind of new to this so I have a question. How do I install the minecraft server 1.5 module via terminal?

Comment: @Loko You should have that installed. I don't use webmin so I'm not sure. I will look to help with that too.

Comment: Thanks man tell me when you found it. I'll try some stuff

Comment: @Loko Good Job! Welcome to linux.

Comment: Haha damn man I am really gratefull man.

Comment: BTW is there anyway to update the version in the server automatically or very easily?

Comment: Well if the downloading and moving to the /usr/local/minecraft folder worked then the easiest method would be when Minecraft updates, then you would want to download and move again following the similar steps but instead of `minecraft_server.1.7.2.jar` it would be `minecraft_server.X.Y.Z.jar` where X would be the Major revision (1 in the sample), Y would be the Minor revision (7 in the sample) and Z would be the patch (2 in the sample).

Comment: How about the world? Will it be available exactly the same as in the previous version?

Comment: @Loko Theoretically yes, you may get a few updates as the patches come out, which add something so it should just update the world file. You can ALWAYS make backups of the world because it is located in /usr/local/minecraft. Just run `mkdir ~/Desktop/minecraftbackup; sudo cp -R /usr/local/minecraft/* ~/Desktop/minecraftbackup/*` Which will copy all files and folders from minecraft to the desktop in a folder called minecraftbackup. Inside that folder will be the 'world' folder which contains your blocks for your server's world. Then try out the world in the new server. P.S. do before the update

Comment: Is the ip for people to connect my ifconfig ip + :25565?

Comment: @Loko [whatismyip.org](http://www.whatismyip.org/) is a thing. Minecraft should automagically find out the port unless you are not using a standard minecraft port. Look into getting a [*.noip.com](http://noip.com) address for free so that you can host a website and the minecraft server. THEN worry about your IP. If you are behind a router learn about [port forwarding](http://portforward.com/). Also you'll need to allow the connections in [`ufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) in Ubuntu distributions.

Comment: @Loko Also, googling some of these things would help. And ufw is a link.

Comment: This deserves alot more vote ups.

Comment: @Loko Did you get anything on automatically updating the server jar?

Comment: didn't update the server jar yet